# Phoenix - import module into config

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

For the local development version of my Phoenix app, I would like to import some secret key data from a `gitignore/` directory into `config.exs`. However, there are two things that I am not sure of:

1. The data that I want to import is just string data - API key, secret key - do I need to define a module, or is there a simpler way to export string data?
2. What is the appropriate import statement to use in `config.exs`, given the following file structure:

   ```
   MyApp/
     |
     - config/
     |    |
     |    - config.exs
     |
     - gitignore/
          |
          - api_key.exs
          - api_secret.exs
   ```

I'm familiar with how to accomplish this in Node, but I'm not sure about how to handle this in Phoenix.

To illustrate what I'd like to achieve, an example from one of my Node apps would look like:

`index.js`

```
const APISecret = process.env.API_SECRET || require('./gitignore/api_secret.js')
const APIKey = process.env.API_KEY || require('./gitignore/api_key.js')
```

where the required files look like

```
module.exports = 'RANDOM_KEY_HERE'
```

How should the data-to-be-ignored be formatted, and what is the appropriate way to access that data in `config.exs`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

And answered my own question...

I added a `dev.secret.exs` file like so:

```
use Mix.Config

config :secret_things, 
  api_key: "NUMBERS",
  secret: "STUFF"
```

and then imported it into `dev.exs` with

```
import_config "dev.secret.exs"
```

and included `dev.secret.exs` in my `.gitignore`. Done.

Comment: If you come across this answer, I'd also suggest checking out @BachirC's, it is also very good and may be appropriate for you.

Comment: I feel uncomfortable with this is approach because you are hiding the environment variables (notice I said variables and not values) used by your app since everything is in your hidden file `dev.secret.exs` instead of `dev.exs`. So, from a first glance at `dev.exs`, you won't have any information on what the app configuration looks like, rendering this file pointless. But that's just my opinion :)

Answer (score 0):

I would rather suggest using a `.env` file a the root of your project where you put all you dev environment variables (Add it to your `.gitignore`). It can look like this :

```
export API_KEY=some_api_key
export API_SECRET=some_api_secret
```

Then, in your `config/config.exs`, export these variables like this :

```
config :secret_things,
  api_key: System.get_env("API_KEY"),
  api_secret: System.get_env("API_SECRET")
```

The cool thing is that Phoenix automatically recognizes the `.env` file so the `System.get_env/1` calls will work without anymore configuration.

You can then access these config variables in your app using `Application.get_env(:secret_things, :api_key)`.

Important : Don't forget to `source .env` when launching your server or IEx in the current terminal tabs. You don't need to source it in a new tab.

Comment: Ah, that's cool. I'm not familiar with the scope of the `source` command, though - would I need to `$ source .env` manually every time I start the app in a new terminal tab?

Comment: Oh I found docs on it - it looks like it'll just run it for the current shell. I like this answer, but I don't like the fact that I (and the other devs on the team) would have to run the additional command when starting the server. I wonder if I could script that into the dev server's startup process...

Comment: I'm upvoting it, though, since I think other devs would benefit from your input.

Comment: You don't need to source it every time, just in the current terminal tabs where you want to fire up your server or IEx (like any other bash script file really). Opening a new terminal tab after the file creation won't require sourcing. I just felt the need to remind it in my answer because it is easily forgotten :) I should maybe edit my answer to clarify this.